# Cancelling HTTP requests in AngularJS using promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise, cancellation, angular-http

I need to be able to cancel an HTTP request in AgularJS if a user clicks on another tab to navigate to a different page. I am using the timeout property of the $http service in order to cancel the request, thusly:

```
$scope.myCustomers = function () {
    $scope.searchResultsPromise = $http.get('/api/customers/getmycustomers', { timeout: canceller.promise } )
        .success(function (data) { $scope.customerSearchResults = data; })
        .catch(function () { alert("There has been an error retrieving search results") }
        );
}
```

and I am cancelling the request like so:

```
$scope.enquiriesSelected = function () {
    $scope.cancelHttpRequests();
    $location.path("/enquiries");
};

$scope.cancelHttpRequests = function () {
    if (canceller) canceller.resolve();
}
```

However, this doesn't appear to work. If I click on the enquiries link to navigate to another view, and then navigate immediately back to the view containing the cancelled promise, the page appears to be 'jammed'. I cannot perform any HTTP requests. Looking in Fiddler indicates that the request is made but it doesn't return.

Does anybody have any experience of cancelling HTTP requests in Angular? I am using version 1.3.15

**UPDATE**

Pierre Gayvallet, I create the canceller in the controller creation function:

```
angular.module('App')
    .controller('customersCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $q, $location, lookupDataService) {
            // ...
            var canceller = $q.defer();
            // ...
})) // these may be incorrect!
```

robertklep, I will add some logic to make sure the promise is not already resolved.

**MORE INFO**

robertklep, there doesn't appear to be a recommended method of checking if the promise is already resolved. I will try and add a flag to the scope, but I am loathe to clutter up my code with stuff like this...

M

Comment: When do you creates you object canceller ?

Comment: Are you reusing `canceller` after it has been resolved already?

Comment: I have answered your questions in the main post above

Comment: @serlingpa you probably have to create a new `canceller` for each request. Once a promise has been resolved, you cannot (AFAIK) reset it so any subsequent connections being made using that (resolved) promise will probably not work properly (which is what you're experiencing).